# Why am I all of a sudden not able to copy a list from one site to another?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

A couple of weeks ago I was one site, went to add new list, and it gave me all sorts of options for copying a list on another site. Doing this also, as a by-product, added the list to the list template gallery.
The options for this seem to have gone when trying to add a new list today. Has there been an update that have removed these options in the last two weeks?

Answer (score 0):

What option has gone? Do you mean that you cannot add the list template into the list template gallery?

Could you please provide more details and screenshot about the issue?

And per my test in my SharePoint online environment, then I can upload the list template into the list template gallery in different site.